# Find the limit of $\frac{1^1+2^2+3^3+\dots +n^n}{ n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

What is the limit of the sequence:
$$\frac{1^1+2^2+3^3+\dots +n^n}{ n^n}$$

I tried only to break it in $(1/n^n)+..+(n^n)/n^n$ and say that the first equals to zero and the last is $1$. I have no idea what to do with the rest. Any ideas?